# show a pop up alert when product is out of stock

Tags: magento2, product-view, out-of-stock, notification

When a product is out of stock, customers will see a pop-up with a message to inform them that the product is no longer available. How can i do that. please help !!

Comment: overide catalog_product_view.xml and call a template file, in template get product stock status for current product and based on that status use a jquery to show out of stock message popup alert

Comment: @Pramod Please help me with that, i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution for you

Create

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Additional" />
</config>
```

Then

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/Additional.php

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional as CoreAdditional;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;

class Additional extends CoreAdditional
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_list;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::product/view/additional.phtml';

    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getChildHtmlList()
    {
        if ($this->_list === null) {
            $this->_list = [];
            $layout = $this->getLayout();
            foreach ($this->getChildNames() as $name) {
                $this->_list[] = $layout->renderElement($name);
            }
        }
        return $this->_list;
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    /**
     * get stock status
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @return bool 
     */
    public function getStockStatus()
    {
        $productId = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getId();
        /** @var StockItemInterface $stockItem */
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($productId);
        $isInStock = $stockItem ? $stockItem->getIsInStock() : false;
        return $isInStock;
    }
}
```

Create a

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/additional.phtml

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional */
?>
<?php foreach ($block->getChildHtmlList() as $_html) :?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_html ?>
<?php endforeach; 

$productStatus = $block->getStockStatus();
if ($productStatus == 0):
?>

<div id="custom-popup-modal">
  <p>The product is out of stock</p>
</div>

<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            modalClass: 'custom-popup-modal',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#custom-popup-modal'));
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#custom-popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        });     
    }
);
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this will help you, let me know if you have any query.

Comment: hi @Arun Kumar I reached an error of construct and then i have edited the file but it doesn't want to work

Comment: Updated my answer please check again

Comment: producrt page view shows: An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

Comment: Check execption.log and debug.log in var/logs

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Wait give me some time I will update the answer with working one

Comment: Hey @NkosinathiMafuleka updated answer and its working. I have tested this please apply and let me know if you have any query

Comment: it working perfectly :). Is there a way to add this modal pop-up if one store doesn't have stock?

Comment: Have to check will let you know tomorrow. Please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: alright cool. it worked perfectly for me. have cast my vote for useful answer. i will appreciate your new edit of above question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138037/discussion-between-arun-sharma-and-nkosinathi-mafuleka).

Answer (score 0):

does this work for products with swatches ?